# Basic Disposable Pattern in F#

Tags: f#, idisposable

According to
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/dispose-pattern#basic-dispose-pattern

The Basic Disposable Pattern requires a *protected* virtual void Dispose(bool) method to be defined in the Disposable class.

However, F# doesn't have the protected modifier, so the closest implementation I can think of is public.

```
type DisposableType () = 
    abstract member Dispose: bool -> unit

    default __.Dispose(disposing: bool) = 
        if disposing then ...

    interface IDisposable with
        member this.Dispose() = 
            this.Dispose(true)
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this)
```

**Is this a valid implementation of the pattern?** I wonder whether .NET uses reflection do discover the virtual Dispose method and explicitly looks for a *protected* method. In this case, there doesn't seem to be a way to fulfil the pattern in F#.

**EDIT**

Some more context after reading Brian Berns [link](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/8463) :

```
type DisposableType (observable: IObservable<unit>) = 
    let mutable subscription = observable.Subscribe(id)

    interface IDisposable with
        member __.Dispose() = 
            if not <| isNull subscription then 
                subscription.Dispose()
                subscription <- null
```

**Dispose pattern is for unmanaged resources**

The field subscription is an IDisposable, however it is a convenience object to remove a delegate handler (when disposed). AFAIK this has nothing to do with unmanaged resources.

**The GC knows how to deal with managed resources**

In this scenario no, it doesn't. If we don't explicitly call subscription.Dispose(), we create a leak, even if there is no native resource or SafeHandle involved.

**We shouldn't create Finalizable objects**

What happens here if the code forgets to dispose of DisposableType instances? AFAIK, we have a leakage problem and the only way I see to fix it is by (probably) providing a finalizer and using a weak reference.

**99% of the cases finalizers are not needed**

I would be surprised if observables are used in only 1% of cases.

Am I missing something?

Comment: .NET doesn't look for anything using reflection. The only part that's actually required is the `IDisposable` implementation, everything else is just "best practice".

Comment: The full pattern is only necessary for base classes, and even then is overkill most of the time. [99% of .net developers should never ever actually implement the "full blown" dispose pattern](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/8463).